# Dynamic multiple vuetify select tags with dynamic options

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Selected option disappears everytime a different v-select tag is clicked

Using v-for and vuetify v-select tag, I'm creating multiple select tags with with one list of choices that changes depending on which select tag the user clicks. The current solution I did was on change/blur I just reinitialize the default list back to the original, but this is causing some problems still.

```
``
<v-select
 :items="timesFrom"
 v-model="time[0]"
 solo
 flat
 hide-details
 height="14"
 @change="setChoicesToDefault"
 @focus="getEvent(day, index, 'from')"
 @blur="setChoicesToDefault"
>
 <span slot="selection">
   {{
    `${time[0] > 12 ? time[0] - 12 : time[0]}:00${
      time[0] > 12 ? ' PM' : ' AM'
    }`
   }}
 </span>
 <span slot="item" slot-scope="data">
   {{
    `${data.item > 12 ? data.item - 12 : data.item}:00${
      data.item > 12 ? ' PM' : ' AM'
    }`
   }}
 </span>
 <v-icon slot="append" small>
  fas fa-angle-down
 </v-icon>
</v-select>
``
```

Below is an example of the default time list:

```
``
defaultTimeFrom: 
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
``
```

I suspect that the reason for this problem is because of the dynamic nature of the choice and since I'm removing the previously selected choice from the list for the other select tags, the previously selected value disappears as well. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: If the new `timesFrom` does not contain the current value of `times[0]` then yes, the selected choice will disappear.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the problem too. Is there any way to save the choices per item so it won't disappear?

Comment: You can wrap `defaultTimeFrom` and `currentChoice` inside another object - and then compose an Array of those objects so that when you switch between these objects both the `:items` and `v-model` will point at their corresponding keys in the currently selected object. Thus you will keep the selected option per each list of items.